# Keeping information private, even from database users

Tags: sql, database, reactjs, security

I have a unique use case. I want to create a front-end system to manage employee pay. I will have a profile for each employee and their hourly rate stored for viewing/updates in the future.

With user permissions, we can block certain people from seeing pay in the frontend.

My challenge is that I want to keep developers from opening up the database and viewing pay.

An initial thought was to hash the pay against my password. I'm sure there is some reverse engineering that could be used to get the payout, but it wouldn't be as easy.

Open to thoughts on how this might be possible.

Comment: DBMSes got Access Rights, Views & Stored Procedures to protect data. Developers do the development on a development system (or datanbabse) where the actual pay is encrypted/randomized. The DBA deploys to production.

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means a comprehensive answer, but I wanted at least to point out a couple of things:

- In this case, you need to **control security at the server level**. Trying to control security at the browser level, using Javascript (or any similar frameword like ReactJs) is fighting a losing battle. It will be always insecure, since any one (given the necessary time and resources) will eventually find out how to break it, and will see (and maybe even modify) the whole database.
- Also, if you need an environment with security, you'll need to separate developers from the Production environment. They can play in the Development environment, and maybe in the Quality Assurance environment, but by no means in the Production environment. Not even read-only access. A separate team controls Production (access, passwords, firewalls, etc.) and deploys to it -- using instructions provided by the developers.

Comment: This is good. I really like point 2. Right now, I have interns building this system and they are the ones I don't want to see each other's pay. I'll eventually have an FTE that can manage the deployment to production.